# Detect button click (by class name) in WKWebView with JavaScript.evaluate

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, macos, wkwebview

I've been attempting to add a listener for when the user click this button element in a WKWebView:

```
<div class="web-navigation__auth" data-test-web-chrome-auth="">
    <button class="web-navigation__auth-button web-navigation__auth-button--sign-in button button-reset button--auth">
        <svg ... ></path></g></svg>
        Sign In
    </button>

    <div class="web-chrome-auth-container__spinner web-chrome-auth-container__spinner--hidden"></div>
</div>
```

I've attempted to observe using numerous different JavaScript evaluations, and have tried the code in different places (ie. `viewDidLoad`, `webView(didFinish)`, `webView(didStartProvisionalNavigation)`, etc):

```
let js1 = "document.addEventListener('click', function(e) { e = e || window.event; if(e.target.getAttribute('class') == 'web-navigation__auth-button') { console.log(e.target.value); } });"
let js2 = "var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('web-navigation__auth'); var myFunction = function() { var attribute = this.getAttribute('web-navigation__auth-button--sign-in'); alert(attribute); }; for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false); }"
let js3 = "document.addEventListener('click', getElementsByClassName('web-navigation__auth-button').onclick();"

webView.evaluateJavaScript(js) { (key, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print(err.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        print("JS: You tapped the Sign In button!")
    }
}
```

The output to console only seems to appear whenever the `webView.evaluateJavaScript` is called, **not** when button is pressed. I have **not** gotten any code to trigger when the button is pressed, aside from the note below regarding `js3`. This the the output to console for each JS call in `webView(didFinish)`:

```
js1: A JavaScript exception occurred     // on webView.didFinish
     JS: You tapped the Sign In button!  // on webView.didFinish

js2: A JavaScript exception occurred     // on webView.didFinish
     JS: You tapped the Sign In button!  // on webView.didFinish

js3: A JavaScript exception occurred     // on webView.didFinish
     A JavaScript exception occurred     // on Sign In button click (fired again)
```

One thing to note about `js3` is that, it will fire the error message on `webView.didFinish`, but it will **also** fire the error if the button is pressed.

So theoretically, I could create a flag to check for the clicking of that button; however, I would prefer something more concrete than this hacky workaround:

```
// Error output to console on every new page load AND "Sign In" button click
var pageLoad = false    // Page has not yet loaded, false by default

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    pageLoad = true     // Page has loaded, unless new URL detected, next error = button click!
    if webView.urlHasChanged() { pageLoad = false }
    
    let js3 = "document.getElementsByClassName('web-navigation__auth-button').onclick();"
    webView?.evaluateJavaScript(js3) { (key, err) in
    if let err = err {  
        if pageLoad {
            // Error message && pageLoad = "Sign in" button pressed: CODE HERE
        }
    }
    if pageLoad && url.hasNotChanged() { pageLoad = false }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by adding a script message handler to userContentController and listening to

```
 func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage){}
```

Below is the full code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Fetch html
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "example", ofType: "html") ?? "")
        let config: WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        // Adding a script message handler
        config.userContentController.add(self, name: "test")
        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: config)
        webView?.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.view.addSubview(self.webView)
        //Load html page
        self.webView?.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
    }

    // Delegate method on click action
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "test", let messageBody = message.body as? String {
            print(messageBody)
        }
    }

}
```

You can use sample HTML with javascript as below

```
<div id="test" style="height: 40px; width: 100px; background-color: powderblue;">Hello</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/platform.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function test() {
    webkit.messageHandlers.test.postMessage("TEXT");
});
</script>
```

Let me know if you are looking for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `WKScriptMessageHandler` without the need of changing your website source code.

Step1. Instantiate your `WKWebView` instance with a registered message handler.

```
let contentController = WKUserContentController()

contentController.add(self, name: "MessageHandler")

let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.userContentController = contentController

let webview = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
```

Step 2. Inject a JS code that listens to the click event and sends a message to the message handler registered above whenever a click event arrived. ***This code MUST be executed AFTER your page is loaded.***

```
let jscode = """
buttonSelector.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  window.webkit.messageHandlers.MessageHandler.postMessage("clicked")
})
"""
webview.evaluateJavaScript(jscode) { _, _ in }
```

Step 3. Handle incoming messages in your app

```
extension YourClass: WKScriptMessageHandler {
  public func userContentController(
    _ userContentController: WKUserContentController,
    didReceive message: WKScriptMessage
  ) {
    print(message) 
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I do this in SwiftUI?