# Printing from WKWebView on button click

Tags: ios, swift, printing, wkwebview

I have a print recipe java script function in the backend login for the employees. So in the normal browser it calls the print windows and it's possible to print.

But in the `WKWebView` it doesn't work. I read and read questions on forums and the apple developer documentation but I could not find a solution.

So how can I detect the print button push on the site, from swift, and call the function which prints the needed area?

I have attached screenshots of my code and the site. The first picture is the site you land on in the app, then you have to login and afterwards click on the order and then on print. screenshots are in this row attached):
[image: landing page]
[image: second page]

My code is:

```swift
import UIKit
import WebKit

class MitarbeiterViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate,UIWebViewDelegate  {
    
    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func loadView() {
       
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let myURL = URL(string:"https://www.pizzeria-lo-straniero.de/mitarbeiterlogin")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)    
    }
    
    func printRecipeWebViewController(){
        //MARK: - PRINT
            
        let webviewPrint = webView.viewPrintFormatter()
        let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
        printInfo.jobName = "page"
        printInfo.outputType = .general
        let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
        printController.printInfo = printInfo
        printController.showsNumberOfCopies = false
        printController.printFormatter = webviewPrint
        printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow ,
Your requirement is certainly possible and it can be done by injecting a script message handler to userContentController. Basically you inject your webview with some JS  so it allows you to listen to the certain actions and then you can perform the required actions in the other end. This detailed answer should assist you with the requirement , please make sure to make a quick search to avoid repetitions of questions

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62743190/9343566.  - Answer 1
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62743190/9343566.  - Answer 2

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have already read these questions and googlet a lot about my problem. But I cant make the transfer from another code to mine. I am not into this topic enough. Maybe you have a tip for me where I can learn about the complete ukwebview ? 
Greetings and thanks a lot for your answer