# How to detect when Button in HTML file is Clicked in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, forms, wkwebview

i made an app with local html file using Xcode and Swift , now i want do something when button is clicked for submitting the form , i have searched a lot but couldn’t find any solutions , please help ..

this is my button

```
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Calculate" onclick="ageCalculate()">Calculate</button>`
```

i want to do something when button Calculate is clicked..

i have tried this method but did not work..

`

```
 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebView.NavigationType) -> Bool {
            
        if (navigationType == .formSubmitted) {
               
            print("Button Clicked in the app")

        
            }
            return true
        }
    `
```

when i change UIWebView.NavigationType to WKWebview then i got this error..

Reference to member 'formSubmitted' cannot be resolved without a contextual type

and same for if i change it to WKNavigation

Comment: `UIWebView` and `WKWebView` are 2 different things and are not interchangeable.  `UIWebView` is deprecated and should not be used. And WKWebView doesn't have such event. You should communicate via JS evaluation or messages, check post I link below

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect button click (by class name) in WKWebView with JavaScript.evaluate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61086342/detect-button-click-by-class-name-in-wkwebview-with-javascript-evaluate)